# == operator in Java

Tags: java, string-comparison

Below code represents the same operation but results getting differes ?
can any one tell me how the java executs the == operation ?

```
          String str = new String("Hello");
          String str1 = new String("Hello");
          System.out.println(str == str1);
```

o/p 
False

```
          String str = "Hello";
          String str1 = "Hello";
          System.out.println(str == str1);
```

o/p 
True

Comment: One quick advice: Always search for a question before posting a new one. This is has been asked a lot of times earlier.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The One line answer for the below statement ,

```
String str = "Hello";
String str1 = "Hello";
str == str1
```

> Both points to the same string literal in the String pool.

And here ,

```
      String str = new String("Hello");
      String str1 = new String("Hello");
```

You are explicitily asking `String` pool to create a new instance of literal "Hello"